# Display all puppeteer plugins on a browser instance

Tags: puppeteer

I have a service that accepts a [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) instance. I want to add a way of warning the developer if the browser instance is using the [`puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth).

How can I easily check which plugins are enabled in a puppeteer browser instance?

```js
function detectStealthPlugin(browserInstance) {
  if (browserInstance.containsStealthPlugin) { // this does not work obviously
    console.warn(" WARNING: you are useing puppeteer with stealth plugin.")
  }
}
```

I know you can use `.plugins` on the puppeteer object, but I cannot find out how to use it on the browser instance.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const isUsingStealthPlugin = (puppeteer) => {
  if (!puppeteer.plugins) {
    return false;
  }
  const pluginsUsed = puppeteer.plugins.map(p => p.constructor.name);
  return pluginsUsed.includes("StealthPlugin");
}

const browserInstance = await puppeteer.launch();
// this works ✅
isUsingStealthPlugin(puppeteer);
// THIS DOES NOT WORK ❌
isUsingStealthPlugin(browserInstance);
```